MariaDB won't free disk space after drop database
I have Test MariaDb 10.6 database installed in our DEV server.
I set a test analytics database on it, just to TEST how an application's built-in monitoring would work (and it worked).
But, due to the hurry, we forgot to disable this monitoring and the database grew up. After some time, I saw 90% of the disk being used by "mariadb" directory.
So, as it was just a test database, I logged into mariadb and ran drop database reports; and I commited the operation.
I thought that this would work but for some reason the disk space wasn't freed.
I checked on other topics and I remember they said to rm the ibd* files (it was really big). But, even after that, the disk space wasn't freed.
Please, is there anything else I should do to free this space?
These are the results of df and du command:
[myusr@mysrv App]$ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
[...]
/dev/mapper/vg_app-lv_app   97G   86G  6.4G  94% /App

[myusr@mysrv App]$ sudo du -sh ./*                                                                                                            
41G     ./MyBigApp
1.4G    ./backups
16K     ./lost+found
409M    ./mariadb

Thank you

restart mariadb.

This question is similar to: Reclaim disk space after deleting Magento MySQL database. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@GeraldSchneider I managed to fix this by running the "lsof +L1" and "kill [pid-of-mariadb]" as I mentioned in my answer on this question. Restarting mariadb for some reasons wasn't working. Thank you!

What was the value of the setting innodb_file_per_table when you created the tables in that database?

@RickJames the values during the table creation was "ON"

After a some search, I found the following question:
No free disk space
I ran the sudo lsof +L1 command mentioned on it and I found a lot of mariadbd items on it.
So, I just ran:
sudo kill [pid-of-mariadbd-in-previous-command]

And the disk space was freed!
I tried before just to restart the database, but that didn't work.
Thank you - I hope this helps someone in the future
